# перенаправление для поддомена

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

Как правильно сделать перенаправление для поддомена?

```
https://www.zh.site.com -> https://zh.site.com/

www.zh.site.com -> https://zh.site.com/
```

Делаю так:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zh\.site\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.zh\.site\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/zh\.site\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Получается:

```
Сайт zh.site.com выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.

Удалите файлы cookie.
```

---

**Update**: Проблему решил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно убрать первую строку полностью:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zh\.site\.com$ [OR]
```

Использовать все остальное:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.zh\.site\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/zh\.site\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

И все будет работать идеально:)